# Constructor on type x not found - Glass Mapper Language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I got a sitecore micro site built with glass mapper and working fine with english version.

www.website.com/?sc_lang=en

But, if i go to French version of the website.

www.website.com/?sc_lang=fr

I end up with an error

> Constructor on type
>   'xxxxx.INest_Landing_Page' not
>   found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
>   'xxxx.INest_Landing_Page' not
>   found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'xxx.INest_Landing_Page'
>   not found.]    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +14259449
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +200    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +28
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ModelLocator.GetModelFromTypeName(String
>   typeName, String model, Boolean throwOnTypeCreationError) +99
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromLayout.GetFromField(Rendering
>   rendering, GetModelArgs args) +336
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromLayout.Process(GetModelArgs
>   args) +102    (Object , Object[] ) +83
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +186
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +197
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +337
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +27
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model() +167
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +158
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/views/shared/xxxst/xxx.cshtml'. ]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you have all the items in the language you selecting and as well that the language is installed (fr-FR) not just (fr)

I guess that should help